# Who will get more benefit if domain1.example is linked to domain2.example

Tags: seo, backlinks, google-ranking

I have two websites, `domain1.example` and `domain2.example`
I have placed a link of `domain2.example` on homepage of `domain1.example`.
I am noticing that `domain1.example` is getting more benefits of that link, as i can see the `domain1.example` is ranking higher that `domain2.example`

But, i want `domain2.example` to rank higher.

Comment: How do you know that domain1 is ranking higher specifically because of that link and not other factors?

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely hard to equate two sites comparative rankings solely to the respective back links as back linking is only one signal that Google uses to rank pages on a website. Additionally simply providing back links won't really make a difference unless the back links appear organic, such as on domain1 having a page discussing the content of a page on domain2 and back linking where appropriate. Linking should be organic in that the link provides further information and benefit to the end user, this is one of the things Google will evaluate when ranking links and the respective linked pages.